# sql negation operators : != vs <>

Tags: sql, negation

Why are there two negation operators in SQL language? `!=` and `<>`.

Are they redundant or is there a difference between them depending on operands ?

Which one should I use to negate strings in `MySQL` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `<>` is ISO Sql Standard
- `!=` is vendor specific

They both have no difference among them. It is just a personal preference which one to use. I always prefer `<>` since it is a *ISO SQL* standard

Answer (score 2):

The SQL standard only specifies `<>` for not equals. SQL:2011 Foundation, section 5.2 *`<token>` and `<separator>`* specifies:

> ```
> <not equals operator> ::=
>   <>
> ```

However some SQL implementations (like MySQL) also support `!=` as a lot of programmers are more familiar with `!=` for not equals. They are fully equivalent, so you can use either, but from a standards point of view you should use `<>`.

See also the MySQL documentation for [not equals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal).

Comment: I wouldn't say "most SQL implementations also support `!=`, but there is no reason for a downvote on this answer.

Comment: @gordonlinoff I replaced it with some; I can't recall seeing one that didn't support it, but as I haven't seen all SQL implementations, most is likely not correct. Thanks.